# Given two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$. Compute $Pr(X-Y<=0)$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

Given two independent discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ that follow the same distribution: Each can take $n^2$ different positive values each with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

I am interested in the probability that $X-Y\leq 0$: $Pr(X-Y\leq 0)$. I know that one can do this by defining $Z:=X-Y$ and computing the distribution of $Z$: $Pr(Z=z)$.

But in this case I will have to go over all possible $z$ and find out how many ways there are to construct $z$, e.g. if $z=5$ and $X$ and $Y$ can take values from ${\lbrace1, ..., 10\rbrace}$ than I have to go over all possible combination on how to construct $5$, so $10-5, 9-4, 8-3, 7-2, 6-1$, since I do not know the exact values $X$ and $Y$ can take (only that there are $n^2$ many) this seems rather unpractical.

Is there a smart way how to do this? Since $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution maybe something like $Pr(Z=z)=$(number of ways to construct $z$)$(\frac{1}{n^2})^2$. But how do I get the number of ways how to construct $z$?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent and uniform?

Comment: You cannot compute this probabiltiy without independence.

Comment: Not necessarily @Vikrant

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you very much for your answer. Why not?

Comment: The question is meaningless in that case.

Comment: May you please explain that a bit more? Why is it meaningless?

Comment: I assume $n^2$ positive values that $X$ and $Y$ can take are same otherwise it does not make sense. Also as KaviRamaMurthy said, $X$ and $Y$ must be independent otherwise you cannot compute the probability.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables aren't independent, there isn't a fixed answer -- it depends on how $X$ and $Y$ are related. Some examples: You could have $X$ and $Y$ linked so that $X=Y$ always; then the probability is $1$. If the distribution is each of $\{1,2,\dots,n^2\}$ with equal probability (for example), then you could have $X=n^2+1-Y$, where the probability is $1/2$.

However, if they're independent, there is a fixed answer. It's better not to think about it in terms of $Z=X-Y$ and instead to think in terms of $\operatorname{Pr}[X\leq Y]$ -- the latter quantity is not really dependent on the possible values of $X$ and $Y$, only their ordering, so you can let $X$ and $Y$ take each $a_i$ with $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_{n^2}$ with probability $1/n^2$, and the question is just the probability that, if $X=a_i$ and $Y=a_j$, $i\leq j$. Can you calculate this directly?

Comment: Are you thinking about doing it with conditioned probability? Something along the lines of $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n Pr(Y=a_j|X=a_i)$?

Comment: Then we can compute $Pr(Y=a_j|X=a_i)=\frac{Pr(Y=a_j  \land X=a_i)}{Pr(X=a_i)}=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Hence, $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n Pr(Y=a_j|X=a_i)=\frac{1}{2}(n^2-1)$. But I think I am doing something wrong since the probability is larger than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: fix $X=x$ (which happens with probability $P[X=x]$, then compute the probability that $Y\geq x$ given $X=x$. Using that, compute $P[X=x \wedge Y\geq x]$. If $X$ and $Y$ are uniform and independent, this should be a simple task. Then sum it over all choices of $X$.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. How do I compute the probability that $Y \geq x$ given $X=x$. This is $Pr(Y\geq x | X=x)$ but for this I will already need $Pr(X = x \land Y \geq x)$. So I guess I am misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Oh, it depends on your distribution. If you know the joint distribution already, then you can directly compute $P[X=x \wedge Y \geq x]$.

Comment: If X and Y are independent isn't this simply $P(X=x)*P(Y\geq x)$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Hope this helps!